# Application crashes (closes) even though exception is being caught

Tags: c#, encryption, key, private

I have the following code:

```
public byte[] GenerateSignature(List<string> text_list)
        {
            StringBuilder text_string = new StringBuilder();
            string private_key = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>zDYX4tbHSy....";
            byte[] digital_signature = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < text_list.Count; i++)
            {
                text_string.Append(text_list[i]);
            }

            try
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                rsa.FromXmlString(private_key);

                RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter rsa_form = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
                rsa_form.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");

                SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
                UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text_string.ToString());
                byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
                digital_signature = rsa_form.CreateSignature(hash);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                digital_signature = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("false");
            }
            return digital_signature;
}
```

Now, if I change a character in the private key, the application crashes and closes on the line `rsa.FromXmlString(private_key)` even though the code is wrapped in a try catch block.  On the other hand, if I set the private key to a meaningless value such as `blablabla`, the exception is caught and handled gracefully.

Why is the application crashing and closing when I change a single character from the private key?  For example, if I change "`<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>zDYX4tbHSy....`" to "`<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>ADYX4tbHSy....`", (changed z to A) the application crashes and closes.  The application is a Windows Phone application but I guess that should not make a difference.

**Update**

This is the call stack just before the exception is thrown:

> MobileApp.dll!MobileApp.Classes.SignatureMobile.GenerateSignature(System.Collections.Generic.List text_list) Line 38    C#
>       MobileApp.dll!MobileApp.StartPage.Button_LogIn_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 74 + 0x4 bytes   C#
>       System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick() + 0x1f bytes 
>       System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick() + 0x1f bytes
>       System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) + 0x4e bytes
>       System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Controls.Control ctrl, System.EventArgs e) + 0xc bytes
>       System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName) + 0x115 bytes 
>       [External Code]

Comment: Presumably you have a stack trace for the crash - what is it?

Comment: What was the type of Exception?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't know.  In fact, Visual Studio does not report an exception.  The application just closes in the emulator, that's all.

Comment: Not so related but useful, Register to UnhandledException on AppDomain, this way you can catch the exception if thrown from your application.

Comment: have you checked whether `text_list` is null?

Comment: Yes.  It is not null.  The application works ok if I don't change the private key.  However, if I change a single character in the private key, the issue arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've just uncovered a bug. I presume that the key value is parsed and then passed on to an underlying native library. The error is not handled gracefully in the underlying library or the wrapper function around it. Note that you've changed the modulus length slightly when you changed the private key from `z` to `A`. The modulus size is now different from the key size. This may not have been tested well.

Congratulations :)

Comment: It would be interesting to try this with a public key. If that works as well, you may have found an exploitable bug.

Comment: Please let us know how you fare with this, I would personally generate a bug report for the library.

Comment: I simulated the bug the other way round, that is, the signature is computed using a public key.  The same bug still crops up if I change a character in the public key.

Comment: I haven't checked whether the exception is caught in another kind of applications e.g. console application.  Therefore, I am not sure if this bug only exhibits itself in the Windows Phone application or in other kinds of applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand, if I set the private key to a meaningless value
> such as blablabla, the exception is caught and handled gracefully.

that suggests different culture setting

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

**Update:**
RSA.FromXmlString Method

The FromXmlString initializes an RSA object using key information in an XML string that was generated using the ToXmlString method. The FromXmlString method accepts either an XML string containing a public key or an XML string containing a public and private key.

this method expects valid RSA key. Valid according to specifications:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.1

If you use private key as described no wonder that it generates exception as private key consists both public and private keys.
On the other hand meaningless key may be interpreted as a public key only.

Comment: Thanks :)  I will look into the matter :)  Thank you :)

Comment: UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text_string.ToString()); are you sure that string after encoding matches pattern?

Comment: Yes, the string matches perfectly after the call as the server authenticates the call.  When the private key remains unchanged, the program works perfectly.  It is when I change a single character in the private key where the program crashes.  However, if I set the private key to something meaningless such as 'hellothere:)', the exception is caught and handled gracefully.  I know, it is very strange.

Comment: do you mean private key? <RSAKeyValue> is a public key

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?